# Problem in Android Database creation. Please help

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to android. I implemented these steps to create a sqlite database,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("TestData.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

   }
```

but the the database not made i searched the database at every location (in packcage also), also checked with commands specified. 
**# ls /com/testproject/action.TestAction/databases**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using this commands here but Android stores the database files in the directory:

```
/data/data/your_app_package_name/databases/
```

I assume if your application have `com.testproject` pakage name in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file then your database file path should be like this:

```
 /data/data/com.login/databases/TestData.db
```

So just insure that your db file is there or not.

Refer this : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial provided by Android Developers. It contains some useful information on general Android things, including how to create an SQLite DB

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

The SQLite stuff is in Exercise 1.